# Capistrano & Ruby 'require' LoadError: cannot load such file -- 'net-http-persistent'

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, rake, capistrano

I have a custom gem that is published only to Github, not rubygems.org, and updated its dependencies to include the gem 'net-http-persistent'.

I followed the same format which I did previously for my other dependencies (using a .gemspec file), and `bundle update` still works just fine. However, now when I try to deploy the main app (which includes my custom gem) to my Staging server with Capistrano, I'm hit with this error:

```
DEBUG [20cee5f9] Command: cd /var/www/inside/releases/20160418182647 && ( RAILS_ENV=staging ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.0@rails4.1 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    LoadError: cannot load such file -- net-http-persistent
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /var/www/inside/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/series25-5465e368ff56/lib/series25.rb:4:in `require'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /var/www/inside/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/series25-5465e368ff56/lib/series25.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /home/charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /var/www/inside/releases/20160418182647/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /var/www/inside/releases/20160418182647/Rakefile:4:in `require'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    /var/www/inside/releases/20160418182647/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [20cee5f9]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
cap aborted!
```

I've been able to replicate the error locally by simply running `rake assets:precompile`. I've tried many potential fixes, including installing net-http-persistent locally and adding it to my Gemfile, but to no avail.

Here's what the custom gem looks like in my gemfile currently:

`gem 'series25', git: 'git://github.com/chapmanu/series25.git'`

I made this issue in a bit of a hurry, so if I'm missing any pertinent information let me know. Thanks ahead of time for helping!

Comment: Does `bundle list` show it's installed? Are you sure you're using the same version of Ruby to install it as well as run it?

Comment: you might have to bump the version of your gem so that your bundled version gets updated. Or try reinstalling the gem.

Comment: @tadman On the staging server both my custom gem and net-http-persistent show up in `bundle list`
And if what you mean is to ask if my local ruby version where I'm deploying from is the same as the version on my server, then yes. Both are at 2.1.0

Comment: @max-pleaner I was wondering if versioning had an effect on it. I haven't bumped the version at all, but I can figure out how to.
I've already tried reinstalling the gem on both the server and locally.

Comment: @homeofmatt i found when building a gem that version bumps & git commits needed to be performed at an annoying frequency. An alternative might be to reference a local path in the Gemfile , which should hot-reload the code.

Comment: @maxpleaner I updated my version.rb file up one patch version and ran `bundle update series25`. It recognized that I had changed the version but I'm still stuck with the same error.

Comment: @maxpleaner, I'd rather not move the gem code over to my app (if that's what you mean) if I can avoid it. We've had this gem for over a year and I haven't had a need to update it until now, and I don't think I'll need to again anytime soon.

Comment: @homeofmatt what i meant by "reference a local path" is to clone the gem to your filesystem and then reference it with `path: "/some/absolute/path"` in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that while the gemspec file needed `spec.add_dependency 'net-http-persistent'`, the file in which I put all of my require statements (In my case & in most cases something like `lib/mygem.rb`) needed `require 'net/http/persistent'`.

Certainly specific to my case with this gem, but hopefully useful to anyone else who runs into a similar problem at some point.